# Visual Svn Server with self-signed SSL Certificates

Tags: svn, ssl, ssl-certificate, visualsvn-server

I used "Visual Svn Server" to create a secure [svn server with self-signed SSL Certificates](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00034/).

It works in most of the time. However at times when I try to use svn I get the following error:

```
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/repo'
svn: PROPFIND of '/repo': Server certificate was missing commonName attribute in subject name (https://svn.mycompany.com)
```

The "Visual Svn Server" certificate contains this information:

```
Subject:
CN  svn.mycompany.com
O   My Company
OU  My Company
L   Rome
C   IT

Issuer:
CN  svn.mycompany.com
O   My Company
OU  My Company
L   Rome
C   IT

Expiration Date:     19/12/2024 09:35:22
Serial Number:       FE95970BCB50523F
Fingerprint (SHA-1): 39422DEE53267B6ED7B16E8921C485215AA1B2CA
```

So I think I have the certificates all set up correctly.

in `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd.conf` i see

```
ServerName "PC-XXXX:443"
```

can this be the problem?

The problem so far occurred only with Windows XP 32 bit.

Visual SVN Server 3.2 x64 is installed in Windows 2008 R2 Server x64.

**UPDATE** by [bahrep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/761095/bahrep)

> For compatibility reasons, VisualSVN Server always sets ServerName to
>   FQDN of the computer. [...] Open httpd-custom.conf, enter the line ServerName 
>   "svn.mycompany.com:443", save the file, restart the server and see if it helps.

**FINAL UPDATE**

after changing httpd-custom.conf adding

```
ServerName "svn.mycompany.com:443"
```

problem solved!

Comment: Is there a chance that you are using a very outdated svn client on the Windows XP machine? What `ServerName` do you see in %VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd.conf? Does it match the svn.mycompany.com common name?

Comment: This server-related question has to be asked on ServerFault, BTW.

Comment: @bahrep thanks for the tip, but I prefer to StackOverflow. On ServerFault I never get any answer.

Comment: @bahrep I am using an older client to the server. However, the client will not be problems with different versions of Windows XP. There seems to be a correlation with Windows XP.

Comment: @bahrep in `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd.conf` i see `ServerName "PC-XXXXXXXXXXX:443"` but `httpd.conf` is autogenerated by VISUALSVN SERVER

Comment: Open httpd-custom.conf, enter the line `ServerName "svn.mycompany.com:443"`, save the file, restart the server and see if it helps.

Comment: @bahrep thanks for your help. If you enter the answer I could give you a vote for the help.

Comment: @bahrep I saw that you're part of the team of visual svn. Why visual svn does not change alone httpd.conf with the server name correctly?

Comment: For compatibility reasons, VisualSVN Server always sets ServerName to FQDN of the computer. We consider improving this in future server updates, BTW. As as sidenote, you can always contact us at support@visualsvn.com with questions and feedback.

Comment: @bahrep `ServerName "svn.mycompany.com:443"` solves the problem!